# Better Element For Placing Advertisements Than <aside>

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup

I got really excited when I read this on [Mozilla Publisher Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document):

> In HTML4, every section is part of the document outline. But documents
>   are often not that linear. A document can have special sections
>   containing information that is not part of, though it is related to,
>   the main flow, like an **advertisement block** or an explanation box.
>   HTML5 introduces the **`<aside>` element allowing such sections** to not be
>   part of the main outline.

I felt equally trumped when I came across this on [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/understanding-aside/):

> Navigation, ads, search boxes, blogrolls and so on are not directly
>   related to the article and therefore do not justify the use of an
>   `<aside>`.

As such, after quite a bit of Googling, I realized that people have mixed opinions. Some agree with the use of `<aside>` for content like ads, but others don't.

**Core Problem:** I am building a technology blog, and ever since the beginning, I wanted the pages (including the articles) to be full-width. This gives me little chance to place an ad in it (Google really doesn't like "ads" in between an article's content).

And when I came across the `<aside>` element I thought I struck a gold mine until I saw the mixed opinions about its use for advertisements.

So, the question is, can someone knowledgeable shed some light on whether it is okay to use `<aside>` for advertisements? Also, are there any semantic alternatives (element or markup)?

Comment: its pretty cool that you care so much about semantics, but ads/links are supposed to have rel="nofollow" anyways, so i don't get why you care that much. i'm not being critical or trolling, just my pov. throw them in a crappy div and be done with them :)

Comment: @albert The thing is, in one of the official docs (unable to find the link) Google specifically states that one should make sure that no ads (and the like) are present in between content for Google to effectively crawl and analyze the page and its content. I am hoping that the `aside` property would help. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's [what the spec says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-aside-element.html#the-aside-element):

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, and which could be considered separate from that content.
>   Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>
> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or
>   sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other
>   content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

Leaving aside the fact that advertising is specifically mentioned as being OK in the second paragraph, the source of the confusion is clear. The two paragraphs are slightly contradictory.

The first paragraph states that it should be used for content **tangentially related to** *and* **considered separate from** the main content.

The second paragraph only requires that the content be **considered separate from** the main content.

I suspect this confusion has come about through the choice of the "aside" name which has "tangentially related to" connotations in English, whereas the alternative rejected name for the element, which was "sidebar" does not.

I'm not wholly sure why "sidebar" was rejected, but possibly it was considered too presentational and insufficiently semantic. Unfortunately in selecting "aside" instead, the author introduced semantics that weren't really intended and aren't helpful.

Fortunately, we don't in this case need to decipher this contradiction. Advertisements are specifically called out as being suitable for `<aside>` so the issue is clearly resolved.

Comment: I've [read that](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#open-issues) *"HTML5 is still a draft. The contents of HTML5, as well as the contents of this document which depend on HTML5, are still being discussed on the HTML Working Group and WHATWG mailing lists."* — so, does this mean, there's a chance that W3 would agree with HTML5 Doctor later on?

Comment: HTML5 is in last call. That means that they are deep into bug fixing stage, not changing fundamentals. The future is not known, and the semantics of elements sometimes change, so it is conceivable that a future HTML might change the meaning of aside sure, but that's true of every element.

Answer (score 2):

While I still wait for answers, I've found an authoritative source, W3, [stating that](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside) `<aside>` can contain advertisements.

> Example of contents
>
> - pull quotes
> - sidebars
> - **advertising**
> - groups of nav elements
>
> etc. Other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

**UPDATE:** In a revision of their article on use of 'aside' element, [HTML5 Doctor states this](http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/):

> With the new definition of `aside`, it’s crucial to remain aware of its
>   context. When used ***within*** an `article` element, the contents should be
>   specifically related to that article (e.g., a glossary). When used
>   ***outside*** of an `article` element, the contents should be related to the
>   site (e.g., a blogroll, groups of additional navigation, and even
>   advertising if that content is related to the page).

Unfortunately, I don't understand how they came to that conclusion, because the HTML5 spec for `aside` does NOT state anything as such and that specifically.

In fact, from I've quoted above, I believe if `aside` in an article can contain pull quotes, so can they advertising (W3C hasn't specifically separated their use cases, and I believe they would, if it has to be that way).

***PS:** I've contacted HTML5 Doctor on this, and will update my answer if I get a reply.*

Answer (score 0):

This is the most relevant conclusion on `aside` that I've come across:

> The `aside` element can now represent secondary content when used
>   outside of an `article`. Keep in mind that aside — and, more generally,
>   secondary content — does not necessarily mean “sidebar”. The style of
>   the content should not dictate the use of the element. For content
>   that is not the primary focus of an article (or page) but is still
>   related to the article (or page), aside is what you need, regardless
>   of its visual design.

Reference: http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/

Basically, it depends on if you use it inside your `article` or outside it. outside being the best for ads.. is how i read it.